# wp trim words function only for first post (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I use function to display last 3 posts form blog. I would like the first post display the title and trim post content with "show more" link and the other 2 posts display only title (without content) with "show more" link.

Now I use:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=3'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
        <p class="news_title"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo wp_trim_words( $title , '4', $more = null ); ?></p></a>
        <div class="post_skrot"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 8, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">show more >> </a>' ); ?></div>

    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

How to modify it?

Comment: add a counter  = 1 before while loop and increment it into the loop. if is 1 display the content, otherwhise not (just title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable that will return `true` if it's the first post, and `false` if not:

```
<?php
//Establish first post check variable
$first_post = true;

query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=3');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
            <p class="news_title"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo wp_trim_words( $title , '4', $more = null ); ?></p></a>
            <?php if($first_post) { ?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 8, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">show more >> </a>' ); ?></div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><a class="button_more" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">show more>> </a></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>

        <?php
        //Change value of $first_post
        $first_post = false;
    endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! @Ben tell me is it possible to move "show more" link to separate div? I would like to style it, but now it is stick to post content.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter before while loop and increment it into the loop. if is 1 display the content, otherwhise not (just title and link '...show more'):

```
<?php
    query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=3');
    $postCount = 1;
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
                <p class="news_title">
                    <?php
                    $title = get_the_title();
                    echo wp_trim_words($title, '4', $more = null);
                    ?>
                </p>
            </a>
            <div class="post_skrot">
                <?php 
                if($postCount == 1){
                    //displays both content and link 'show more'
                    echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), $num_words = 8, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">show more >> </a>'); 
                }else{
                    //displays only link 'show more'
                    echo '... <a class="button_more" href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">show more >> </a>';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
        $postCount++;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

With such counter you can define on how many posts content to be displayed, and how many to have only title.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @mitkosoft said in the comments, you want to add a counter to your while loop to determine whether this is the first iteration. If it is, then add the additional information and if it's not add nothing.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=3'); ?>
<?php 

    $counter = 0;

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
                <p class="news_title"><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo wp_trim_words( $title , '4', $more = null ); ?></p>
            </a>
            <?php if($counter < 1):?>
                <div class="post_skrot"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 8, $more = '... <a class="button_more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">show more >> </a>' ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php $counter++; ?>        
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The key part of this solution is the addition of `$counter`, the `if($counter < 1)` statement and the counter increment `$counter++`. If you decided you wanted more than 1 post with trimmed words you could just increase the number in the if statement like this: `if($counter < 5)` which would give you the first 5 posts with trimmed words.

**Note:** One classic mistake people make with counters and loops is not incrementing the counter so make sure you include the `$counter++` line.

---

**Further Reading:**

- [While Loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)
- [If statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
- [Alternative Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (The `if($counter < 1): ?>` part )